# D Language Static Class Function Undefined Identifier

Tags: d

I started learning the D programming language(it's pretty awesome), and ran into a slight problem when I started to explore functions. The setup is pretty basic; it's just a way to figure out the similarities of the language to others that I have used. Here is my class declaration:

```
module TestClass;
import std.string;
class TestClass
{
    this()
    {
        // Constructor code
    }

    public static string getData(){
        return "Test";
    }
};
```

and here is my main:

```
module main;

import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import TestClass;

void main(string[] args)
{
    writeln(TestClass.getData());
    stdin.readln();
}
```

There seems to be an issue with calling the static function in TestClass. I get a "undefined identifier" error. Here is a picture:

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I tried looking through the documentation on the digital mars website, but to be honest it is a little counter-intuitive.

Comment: Which version of D are you using?

Comment: @cfh Whatever is current. I think I just found the answer though. It's odd, and I don't really like it personally...but this is a module error. To get it to work I have to type TestClass.TestClass.getData(); I am looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not having a D compiler handy right now and not having worked with the language in a while, I think I remember having similar problems when starting out in D.

I think the `import` statement pulls in the module `TestClass`, so when you type `TestClass.getData()`, the compiler thinks that you are referring to a global function `getData` in the `TestClass` module.

You can fix this in several ways:

- Rename the `TestClass` module to something else. This will avoid the name clash between the module and the class. As Jonathan M Davis notes in the comments, the convention in the D community is to use lowercase characters for modules, so you could simply rename it to `testclass`.
- Import the class explicitly:

  ```
  import TestClass : TestClass;
  ```
- Write `TestClass.TestClass.getData()` to refer to the class inside the module.

It should also be pointed out that, unlike in Java, classes don't need to be each in a separate module in D.

Comment: Can I define a class without it being within a module? I know this is a separate question...

Comment: @Krythic: Sure, this isn't Java.

Comment: Can you add an example to your answer showing this as well?

Comment: On a related note, it's generally considered best practice to name your modules with all lowercase names, which prevents issues over whether the file system is case-sensitive, and it would make it so that `TestCase` and the module name do not conflict.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis This is the workaround I was looking for; thank you.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work if the class is not within a module. Is there a special keyword I should be using? I did import TestClass, which is just an actual class without a module handle.

Comment: @Krythic: You don't need to import anything if the class is defined in the same source file where you use it.

Comment: @cfh It's in a separate file called TestClass.d

Comment: @Krythic: Every separate source file is considered a module in D.

Comment: So your previous statement was false? =P I will just have to get accustomed to the new "import Class:Class" style. I don't know why they don't have it so I can just write "import Class" though.

Comment: @Krythic: It wasn't false: you can put the class definition in the same source file where you use it. Also, as Jonathan said, simply rename your module to be lowercase.

Comment: A class has to be in a module, but you can have multiple (or zero) classes in a single module.